# Excel: Get Data -> From Web

Tags: excel, powerquery

I i am gather information about stock prices. I am using Power Query in Excel to gather this information from the web page "https://www.investing.com/indices/omx-copenhagen-25-components".

On this web page, it is also possible to acquire information about "Technical", "Performance" and "Fundamental" for each of these stocks. However, I would like to gather these informaiton, also with Power Query.

Here is where the problem begins. I am doing the following process:

Open Excel -> Get Data -> From Web -> Paste this page https://www.investing.com/indices/omx-copenhagen-25-components ->

From here it only shows the table with prices and not the other tables. Does anyone have an idea how to overcome this problem? I have inclosed a picture of the webpage.

Can anyone helpe me with this problem?

\Mathias

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the URL each of the tabs that you press are separate pages. 
Technical is https://m.investing.com/indices/omx-copenhagen-25-technical

You'll need a query for each of the pages as the tables are not under the same page

Comment: Thank you for your input. However, I tried to use your idea and changed "-technical" with the different objects such as "performance" and "Fundamental". But I could see that the objects that I was allowed to change was the different objects: "General", "Chart", "Technical" and "Forum". Included their respectives subobjects. 
So far I have tried your method to find the 3 different selected filters "Price", "Performance" and "Fundamental" under the selected object, "Components". Do you think there is another approach to find these and loading these data with Excel -> From Web

/Mathias